# android: Dialog, cancel button

Tags: android, dialog

I have created a custom dialog, And I have inserted two buttons, one is called send, and the other cancel.

I would like to know hot to close down the dialog when pressing cancel?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you using the AlertDialog.Builder? There are lots of way of implementing a custom Dialog but assuming your "Send" button is a positive or neutral button and your "Cancel" button is a negative button you can always do this.

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        dialog.dismiss()
}
```

You can also call *dialog.cancel()* if you want to invoke the *DialogInterface.OnCancelListener*.

If this is not the case you need to supply additional information.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");


Button cancle_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancle_btn);
dialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    // Perform button logic
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```