# Add a cancel button to a dialog

Tags: java, android

i have dialog with onclick button and include  `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);` how i can add cancel button  to my dialog for hide dialog
and my content layout is different from activity main layout
sorry for my  language

my code :

```
public void showd(View view){

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();

        }
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4053395/1531971

Comment: @Jack In your custom layout add cancel button.

Do findViewById on your dialog object and get its reference.
apply click on that view recieved and in on click just use

dialog.dismiss();

Comment: didn't helped me @jdv

Comment: i do that but i get error @ubhusri

Comment: "Didn't help me" _How_ did it not help. Be specified about what you try and what results you get.

Comment: I think you can do more researches.. there are tons of questions about it on SO.. just google for "how to use alertdialog on android"

Comment: i searched it but i get dialog without content view and content view without cancel button @PierGiorgioMisley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a DialogBuilder instead of creating the Dialog yourself. You then can create a cancel button using the following code

```
// Create your dialog builder
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
// Apply your custom view
builder.setView(R.layout.custom);
// A null clickListener will cancel the dialog
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel" /*TODO Replace with string resources*/, null);
// Show the dialog
builder.show();
```

Comment: when i put yor code inlaid onclick i get error Cannot resolve symbol 'AlertDialog

Comment: When you use Android Studio, try to do Alt+Enter on the AlertDialog. It will then ask you to "Import class". Click on that and you should be fine. (If it asks you which class, select "android.app.AlertDialog")

Comment: ok it working but you can give other code for create another button for do some thing said cancel button

Comment: You can use `builder.setPositiveButton("Your Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(...)` to add another button. The negative button thing in my code above just creates a cancel button, as you wanted in your question.

Comment: thanks you so much but someone give me down vote -_-